# Is 0.00…001 a real number?

Tags: real-numbers

Is $0.\overline{0}1 \in \mathbb{R}$?
If so, is $0.\overline{0}2>0.\overline{0}1$ and $0.\overline{0}1 \neq 0$?
If not, is there a way to define the smallest Number that is not $0$?

Comment: no it is not, take any number $x$ then $x/{2}$ is closer to $0$

Comment: The symbol $0.\bar{0}1$ does not exist as a real number. The closest concept is the idea of infinitesimals in non-standard analysis.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by the expression ${0.\overline{0}1}$ in the first place, and there does not seem to be a sensible way to do so. At first glance, the expression hints at a smallest positive real number, which is obviously nonsense. And so I cannot imagine there being a sensible way of defining it

Answer (score 1):

Define a number, say $r$, that is "the smallest number not 0" then $r/2\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r/2>0$, a contradiction, so, no, there isn't any way to define the smallest number not 0.